# How mark a Service Bus message as processed from an Azure function?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have two very simple NodeJS based Azure function, one which pushes an event to a Service Bus queue:

```
import { Context } from '@azure/functions';

export async function run(context: Context, myTimer: any): Promise<void> {
  context.log('Function started!');

  context.bindings.taskQueue2 = [{ message: 'Some task message' }];

  context.log('Function finished!');
}
```

and an another which reads the message, logs it's content and then exists:

```
import { Context } from '@azure/functions';

export async function run(context: Context, myQueueItem: any): Promise<void> {
  // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---message-metadata
  context.log('Node.js ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message', myQueueItem);
  context.log('EnqueuedTimeUtc =', context.bindingData.enqueuedTimeUtc);
  context.log('ExpiresAtUtc =', context.bindingData.expiresAtUtc);
  context.log('DeliveryCount =', context.bindingData.deliveryCount);
  context.log('MessageId =', context.bindingData.messageId);
  // I have tried with both calling and not calling context.done
  // context.done();
}
```

The related parts from my `host.json`:

```
{
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 512,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:10:00"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

What I would expect that calling the first function once would result in:

- one message is pushed to the service bus queue (works)
- the second function would read that message (works)
- the second function would marke it as processed when exiting without error (doesn't work)

However what I see instead is the second function re-receives the message from the queue until `DeliveryCount` reaches the limit.

My questions are:

- Why the task is not marked as complete automatically when the task is finished?
- How can I mark it as complete manually if messages are not marked as finished by default?

Comment: So you want to mark the message as processed?

Comment: Yes, basically. However from reading the docs, especially the explanation of messageHandlerOptions.autoComplete I would expect that I don’t have to do it manually, just return from my function without raising an error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the host.json you provided, you set the `autoComplete` as false. If you want to mark the message as `complete`, we need to manually call the method `complete()`. For more details, please refer to the [docuemnt](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34013) 
[image]

But according to my research, at the moment, the `autoComplete: false` is only useful for C# function. For more details, please refer to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31958#issuecomment-495485301). So I suggest you set the `autoComplete` as true. It will call `Complete` on the message if the function finishes successfully, or calls `Abandon` if the function fails. For more details, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---peeklock-behavior)